# Logback writes to both Tomcat directory and project folder

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, logback

I use `Tomcat` as a web-server for my web-application and `Logback` as a logging framework. My app consists of some modules and each of them contains `logback` calls. I specified the following `logback.xml` configuration:

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">

<appender name="ACTION-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>action_log.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level %logger{10}[%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

 <logger name="action" level="${logger.level.root:-INFO}" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="ACTION-FILE"/>
    </logger>

<root level="${logger.level.root:-INFO}">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />

    </root>

</configuration>
```

So the problem is that i'm finding `action_log.log` not only in tomcat folder but throughout project. Could you please help me with finding out the problem?

P.S. This issue is reproducible for different IDEs.

Comment: What do you mean by "throughout project"?  Also, are the logs the same, e.g. is the same log entry being logged twice?

Comment: throughout project I meant in every service I use logger for. Yes, logs are exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

The logback file appender will use the filename relative to the logging class. If you want to use a centralized log file you could for example set a property of the logging directory and configure the filename accordingly.

```
<property name="LOG_DIR" value="/home/user/tomcat/logs" />
```

in your logback config and

```
<file>${LOG_DIR}/action_log.log</file>
```

in your appender configuration.

See https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html for further details on the configuration.